# Edit and save the publish file ssdt

Tags: deployment, sql-server-2008-r2, visual-studio-2013, sql-update, sql-server-data-tools

Is there a way to customize and save publishing scripts in a Database project?
If I want to modify some columns and this might incur data loss, or the other way around I want to populate columns in order to be able to modify the column type (to not null) how can I do that with SSDT in visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Modify Columns w/ possible data loss - you'll need to enable the option when publishing to allow possible data loss or that won't be run.

Populate columns to modify - best way would be a pre-deploy script, probably checking to make sure that there are NULL values to update before doing the update. You'll need to add a script of type pre-deploy if one doesn't already exist, then either drop your code straight in that script or create a new script of type "not in build" and include that file in the pre-deploy script.

http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2012/11/ssdt-pre-and-post-deploy-scripts.html